# Why is PackageInfo.requestedPermissions always null?

Tags: android

I'm trying to enumerate all the permissions used by all the installed packages, however when I check the [requestedPermissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#requestedPermissions) property for each of my installed packages it is always null.

Comment: So... have you solved the problem or is there a new question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just needed to pass the PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS flag to getInstalledPackages(). Here is a code snippet.

getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);